# Having issues with distinct in JPA

Tags: java, oracle11g, jpa-2.0, distinct

Using JPA, I want to select all Log objects for a specific actiontype. From the log object I want to get the user (log.getUser()), but the users appear several times in the result list. I tried it with `distinct`, but it did not work, I guess because I was not able to define, what exactly has to be `distinct`. Here is my JPA query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT log 
  FROM Log AS log JOIN log.action AS action 
              JOIN log.user AS user 
 WHERE action.actionType = :actionType
```

If I say `SELECT DISTINCT user`, then I don't have the whole log object in the end.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Part of my Log Class:

```
public class Log {

    private int logId;
    private Calendar logDate;
    private User user;
    private Action action;
    private String description;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Use `group by actionType`, not `distinct`.

Comment: No that is wrong. I want to have all users for a specific action type. Now I get all the users, but if one users has 3 log entries, then 3 times the same user is in the list. That's why distinct should be used .

Comment: Your question is contradictory. First you say that you want the logs for a specific action type, and then in the comment, you say that you want the users for a specific action type. Choose what you really want.

Comment: I want to have the complete log object, but the users in the log object have to be distinct.

Comment: could you post the `Log` class?

Comment: Done, I posted the Log class!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your request, you have one user to one log object, you wanna the log objects and the users... but you don't want repeated users, would it make more sense two queries? One for the logs and other for the distinct users of that logs?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? List all logs grouped by user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two Queries Solution

Since you want `Log` objects and `distinct User` objects you could do two queries, first one to retrieve the `Log` objects and second one to retrieve `distict User` objects.

```
// first one to select Log objects
String logQuery = "SELECT l FROM Log l WHERE l.actionType = :actionType";
...
List<Log> logs = logJpaQuery.getResultList();

// second one to select distinct users from this objects
String usersQuery = "SELECT distinct l.user FROM Log l where l.logId in (:logIds)";
...
userJpaQuery.setParameter("logIds", logs);
List<User> users = userJpaQuery.getResultList();
```

With this approach you have the distinct users for the select `Log`s objects.

Comment: Thanks Francisco! I think my initial request is not possible with one query. I just noticed that. I decided only to select the user. So I ended up with this query: `SELECT DISTINCT user from Log AS log JOIN log.action AS action JOIN log.user AS user WHERE action.actionType = :actionType`

Comment: I see, this means I won the bounty? ;)